# CollectionsFS File is not uploaded to server

Tags: javascript, meteor, image-uploading

i am working myself through the discover meteor project (microscope) and tried to add a file upload, which i wanted to do by CollectionFS. My microscope implementation is quite minimal. I am trying to rebuild a minimal dribbble or Workdesk show and tell website.

I installed:
cfs:standard-packages
cfs:filesystem
cfs:ui

Next I am having a collection called rooms which stores a room with a name, for a user (lib/collections/rooms.js):

```
Rooms = new Mongo.Collection("rooms");
```

And a roomImages CollectionFS Collection (lib/collections/roomImages.js):

```
var imageStore = new FS.Store.FileSystem("roomImageStore", {
    path: "upload", 
    maxTries: 5 //optional, default 5
});

RoomFS = new FS.Collection('roomImages', {
    stores: [imageStore],
    filter: {
        allow: {
            contentTypes: ['image/*']
        }
    }
});

RoomFS.allow({
    insert: function () {
        return true;
    },
    update: function () {
        return true;
    },
    remove: function () {
        return true;
    },
    download: function () {
        return true;
    }
});
```

As I have removed referencing for reducing the debug effort I have this publications.js

```
Meteor.publish('rooms', function() {
    return Rooms.find();
});

Meteor.publish('singleRoom', function(id) {
    check(id, String);
    return Rooms.find(id);
});

Meteor.publish('roomImages', function(){
    return RoomFS.find();
});
```

Inserting a room works. After the room initially is created, the user then is routed to the rooms editing page.

```
<template name="roomEdit">
    <form class="main form">
        <input name="files" type="file" class="fileUploader" multiple>
        {{#each images}}
            {{#unless this.isUploaded}}
                {{> FS.UploadProgressBar bootstrap=true}}
            {{/unless}}
        {{/each}}
    </form>
</template>
```

I took the function off the documentation in the readme:

```
Template.roomEdit.events({
    'change .fileUploader': function (event, template) {
        FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
                RoomFS.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
            //Inserted new doc with ID fileObj._id, and kicked off the data upload using HTTP
            });
        });
    });
```

Now in my collections there are
cfs._tempstore.chunks
cfs.roomImages.filerecord

after trying to upload one image (the progress bar is not showing) cfs.roomImages.filerecord has the file as collection item, but the uploads folder keeps being empty, therefore I think the file is not uploaded, also if I don't give a path, the default folder is not generated.

I have already read both documentations (website and github) and tried different examples, but most of them seem to be outdated.

Am I missing something? I have no real idea why the file is not uploaded to the server.

Comment: just to be sure, are you subscribing to the FSCollection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the subscription on the client, try this code.

First on the `/lib/collection.js` folder declare the FSCollection like this

```
var imageStore = new FS.Store.FileSystem("roomImageStore", {
path: "upload", 
maxTries: 5 //optional, default 5
});

 roomImages = new FS.Collection('roomImages', {
    stores: [imageStore]
});
```

And not the Same file **subscribe** to the FSCollection.

```
    if(Meteor.isClient) {
Meteor.subscribe('RoomFS');
}
```

Now on the `/server/collections.js` make the same publish you have.

```
Meteor.publish('roomImages', function(){
  return roomImages.find();
});


 roomImages.allow({
   insert:function(userId,doc){
      if(Meteor.userId()){
      return true; //if user is logged we return true
     } else{
      console.log("some foreign user try to upload a file take care"); //server log
     return false
   }
}
})
```

we create and subscribe the FSCollection on the `/lib` folder.. why? because the lib folder its the firs thing meteor loads, so with that we have the fsCollection available on both `server/client`.

Now we need to upload a new file, so lets create a **example template**

First we don't want the file to load when we click "accept" on the file input so lets put a `submit file button`, so the html looks like this.

on `Client/exampleUpload.html`

```
<template name="example">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label>Upload the Image</label>
  <input id="testImage" type="file">
  </div>
 <button type="submit" id="uploadTest"> Click to upload</button>
</template>
```

on `Client/exampleUpload.js`

```
    //events
    Template.example.events({
    'click #uploadTest':function(){
        var file $('#testImage').get(0).files[0] / here we store the file
        var fsFile = new fsFile(file); // here we add to the fsFile instance
        fsFile.metadata = {
         coolTextToImage:"this is a cool text"  // here we add some metadata to the fs file
           } 
        if(file === undefined){
           alert("IF NOT IMAGE NOT INSER") //here we add some validation
       } else{
          roomImages.insert(fsFile,function(err,result){
             if(err){
               console.log(err.reason) // here we check if some error occurs when inserting
            } else{
              console.log(result) // if everything ok, wee should see a console.log with some like [Fs.file] object
         }
      })
     }
   }
 })
```

**Edit**

I recommend you to use gridFS,check at  [this](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/issues/423) gitHub issue and also if you use FSfileSystem on production on each deploy the files will be deleted(i think [Modulus.io](https://modulus.io) respect the Path).

How to fix it? use the other 2 adapter [gridFs](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-filesystem) or [s3](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-s3), in my case i use GridFS, and [GraphicsMagic](http://www.graphicsmagick.org) Package

So first Install the GM package

```
meteor add cfs:graphicsmagick
```

With this package you can control the `size, type, etc of the file(image)`

And declare the new FsCollection like this

```
imageStore = new FS.Collection("imageStores", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.GridFS("imageStore",{
    beforeWrite:function(fileObj){
      return {
            extension: 'png',
            type: 'image/png'
          };
    },
    transformWrite:function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream){
      // Aqui la convierte en una imagen segun de 10x10 seguuuun
         gm(readStream).resize(400).stream('PNG').pipe(writeStream); //resize depends your needs
    }
  })]
});
```

**this is just a recommendation if you are planning deploy the app**

Tell me if works, GL

Comment: Thank you so much for this advice, this problem gave me headache at least. I thought of gridfs as well (which I use for now) but in my mind, storing images in the mongodb with the 30% overhead, no cache and no additional compression, I think for scale the only alternative at the moment is S2.